# Clear the app data if disconnected from internet for more then 5min in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, react-native-community-netinfo

I want to clear the react native app data if my app is disconnected from internet for more than 5 min.

I am using react native **NetInfo** to check network connectivity status.
Saving the time when app disconnected and checking when it will reconnect to internet.
If interval is more than 5 min then I want to clear the app data.

My Code is:

```
class OfflineMessage extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isConnected: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      this.handleConnection(state.isConnected);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.removeEventListener((state) => {
      this.handleConnection(state.isConnected);
    });
  }

handleConnection = (isConnected) => {
  this.setState({ isConnected });

  if(!isConnected){
    this.startTimer();
  } else {
    this.checkElapsed();
  }
};

startTimer = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Internet disconnected at: ');
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('time', JSON.stringify(Date.now()));

  } catch (error) {
    // console.log('Something went wrong', error);
  }
}

checkElapsed = async () => {
    try {
      let startTime =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('time');

      if(startTime){
        let endTime = Date.now();
        const elapsedTime = Math.floor((endTime -JSON.parse(startTime))/1000);
        if(elapsedTime > 5){
           alert("5 min is completed.");
           // Clear app data
         }
        console.log('Time elapsed'+ elapsedTime);
      }

  } catch (error) {
    // console.log('Something went wrong', error);
  }
}
```

**Problem**:
Both the methods startTimer and checkElapsed called whenever connectivity status changes.
What is wrong with this code.

if I modify given code as :

```
    state = {
      isConnected: true
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromNetInfo = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
          this.handleConnection(state.isConnected);
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.unsubscribeFromNetInfo();
  }

  handleConnection = (isConnected) => {
    console.log(isConnected);
    this.setState({ isConnected });
};
```

EventListener called multiple times and status changes frequently true false,true,false .

Comment: "Both the methods startTimer and checkElapsed called whenever connectivity status changes" are they **not** called or **are** they called.

Comment: both are called.

Comment: So why is that a problem then?

Comment: if isConnected false both method called, only startTimer should be called. and when reconnected to internet only checkElapsed method should be called.

Comment: You intentionally removed render method of the component right?

Comment: Yes, Its just rendering connectivity status message

Comment: There's actually a few issues there... just me a second :)

Comment: The listener is only called when state changes so you need to add "setTimeout" on startTimer for 5 minutes and clear "setTimeout" variable if connected before 5 minute. Right now your listener is called once not unless state changes and no calculation is done.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you are handling the NetInfo subscription wrong, according to https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo#usage

You would have to do:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromNetInfo = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
        this.handleConnection(state.isConnected);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromNetInfo();
}
```

Also, if you want to check for 5 **minutes** use:

```
if (elapsedTime > 5 * 60)
```

as your conversion

```
Math.floor((endTime - JSON.parse(startTime)) / 1000)
```

converts it to seconds not minutes.

In the current state, your app will trigger almost everything as the code only checks for 5 seconds.

Otherwise, the logic that you implemented itself should be working :)

Comment: One issue here ,NetInfo connectionChange will called multiple times, why?

Comment: I think it is initially called when the module itself is not connected yet, and then after that once it's refreshed. This should not be a problem tough as it's under 5 minutes anyway right?

Comment: I just checked and logged NetInfo is the very root of the project and yes the listener is called twice. If this is an issue for you, (which I think it is) save the last state in the component and only trigger the handle if the differ

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/issues/217#issuecomment-538337844